# Getting this error 'services config should be a array' in my gitlab cicd pipeline

Tags: typescript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, webdriver-io

I am trying to configure a pipe line in gitlab for webdriverIO typescript cucumber framework tests. I wanted to run wdio.conf.ts in the pipeline. But i am getting this error:
[Gitlab pipeline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwKrQ.jpg)
Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
services: 
    webdriverio:
        image: huli/webdriverio:latest
        depends_on:
            - chrome
            - firefox
            - hub
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        volumes:
            - ./wdio.conf.ts:/app

    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - 4444:4444

    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        depends_on:
            - hub

    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        depends_on:
            - hub      
            
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  services:
    - webdriverio
  script:
    - echo "Installing dependencies"
    - npm install

Smoke-Test:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  services:
    - webdriverio
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - npm run wdio
```

I am trying to configure a pipe line in gitlab for webdriverIO typescript cucumber framework tests. I wanted to run wdio.conf.ts in the pipeline.

Comment: Although, they do share some similarities, the [`services:` schema in `.gitlab-ci.yml` CI configurations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#services) is _not_ the same as the `services:` schema you may be familiar with from the Docker Compose schema. I recommend looking at the examples from the GitLab docs. Hope that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `services` variable an array per error, like so -

```yml
services:
     - webdriverio:
     # rest of the definition
```

Check [Keywords Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html) for more details.